# What is the difference between "sinmortigi" and "memmortigi"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

As I understood the difference between "sin-" and "mem-":

```
Mi sinmortigis.
```

> I killed myself (I killed *me*)

```
Mi memmortigis la ŝafon.
```

> I killed the sheep myself (I killed it *on my own*)

But someone told me that "*sinmortigi*" and "*memmortigi*" are actually the same! Really? Reta Vortaro says that "*sinmortigo*" = "*memmortigo*". Is that true, and should we avoid that?

Comment: What about *memfido* then? Should it really be *sinfido*?

Answer (score 7):

Normale la verbo "memmortigi" bezonas rektan komplementon: Oni memmortigas sin. Mi memmortigos min. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj el [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com) pri „memmortigi”:

- Ĉu oni estas certa, ke li sin memmortigis? petis la markizo.
- Kiam oni estis certiginta al li, ke la junulo sin memmortigis, lia konvinko estis iom ŝancelita.
- La malfeliĉulo sin memmortigis.
- Kelkajn tagojn antaŭ kiam ŝi provis sin memmortigi.
- Li konfesis al ŝi sian perfidon kaj ŝi provis memmortigi sin.
- Iam mi pensis, ke mi certe neniam memmortigos min.
- Mi pensis, ke certe neniam iu aktiva esperantisto memmortigus sin.

Vi vidos, ke ĉiam temas pri suicido, ne pri mortigo de iu/io alia, ĉar sekvas la rekta komplemento „sin” aŭ „min”. Teorie vi povas uzi alian rektan komplementon kiel en „Mi memmortigis la ŝafon”, se vi volas traduki *I killed the sheep myself*, sed multe pli kutime oni dirus: Mi mortigis la ŝafon mem.

Answer (score 1):

My own **personal** feeling is that *memmortigo* should be less preferred than *sinmortigo*. Regardless of your or my feeling on this matter, they are listed in many dictionaries as synonyms, and *memmortigo* (I'm a little surprised to find out) is vastly more common.

Comment: Odd; I've seen "sinmortigo" in a few different contexts, but haven't seen "memmortigo" except in dictionaries and such. Not that I have very comprehensive experience, but it seems that if "memmortigo" were vastly more common, I would have seen it in use at some point. :-/

Comment: My subjective experience is the same as yours. However, I based the comment in my answer on a search in the Tekstaro where *memmortigi* is more common by many times over.

Comment: Upon reading Paŭl Peeraerts's answer and revisiting the Tekstaro, I confess I'm even more surprised. *Memmortigi* is rarely used as a verb, and *sinmortigo* only shows up as a verb one time. As he said, most (but not all) appearances of *memmortigi* include the reflexive pronoun. Again, my subjective impression is that *sinmortigi* is the "right" way to say it.